# Segmentation fault with two pointers iterating through a map while concurrently changing the map

Tags: c++

I am new to cpp, and have a piece of code to run:

```
void particleFilter::mergeFilters(double mergeBound){
    for(map<int, filter>::iterator fi = filters.begin(); fi != filters.end();){
        for(map<int, filter>::iterator ji = filters.begin(); ji != filters.end(); ){
            Rect recI = (fi -> second).getRecFilter();
            Rect recJ = (ji -> second).getRecFilter();
            double dis = (double)sqrt((double)(recI.x-recJ.x)*(recI.x-recJ.x)+(double)(recI.y-recJ.y)*(recI.y-recJ.y));
            if(dis<mergeBound && dis>1){
                double wi = (fi -> second).pi;
                double wj = (ji -> second).pi;
                cout <<"call remove function" << endl;
                if(wi<wj){
                    cout << "remove id is " << (fi->second).objectID << endl;
                    removeFilter((fi->second).objectID);
                    fi++;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "remove id is " << (ji->second).objectID << endl;
                    removeFilter((ji->second).objectID);
                    ji++;
                }
            }
            else{
                ++ji;
            }
        }
        ++fi;
    }
}
```

It just has two pointers to compare every two entries of the map, but meanwhile, it deletes some entries of the map. There is nothing wrong with in the `removeFilter((fi->second).objectID);` function for sure.

Anybody has any idea, why segmentation fault?

Comment: how about you debug your code?

Comment: @DanielSanchez You know I've been editing the post with some more than just adding the code block...

Comment: @DanielSanchez Also, how about you suggest particular debugging method?

Comment: mmm the first thing to test: ¿if fi==ji) doest make sense?

Comment: Where is `removeFilter`. Note that once you modify the `map` (insert, erase) erased iterators become in invalid state.

Comment: You have to be carefull when the filter to be removed is fi or ji

Comment: Some additional notes: the second for loop could start at fi+1, instead of the beginning of the map. That already saves you half the execution time. If you are working with C++11, the expression `map<int, filter>::iterator` could be replaced with `auto`. The casts to double on the sqrt line are unnecessary, and in fact, so is the sqrt itself (just be sure to use the square of mergeBound).

Answer (score 3):

You need to change this code:

```
                removeFilter((fi->second).objectID);
                fi++;
```

to something like:

```
auto tmpIt = fi;
fi++;
removeFilter((tmpIt->second).objectID);
```

And make a similar change to the equivalent `ji` code also.

This is because the iterator which is erased is invalidated even though no other iterators to the container are. You are thus modifying an invalidated iterator, which is undefined behaviour. Making a copy and incrementing it first solves the problem.

Comment: Yes it is, a `map::erase` operation is guaranteed not to invalidate any iterators to the map other than the one being erased.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Since C++17, erase also returns the iterator to the next element.

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove a filter which is controlled by fi or ji and after that try to use this variables (for example, as ++fi ++ji)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to increment `fi` in the inner loop without checking if `fi != filters.end()`